# Text in box not centered

Tags: html, css

Text is not centered and is more to the right.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: `ul.navbar li {text-align:center;}`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/20mv1ufj/2/ check my fiddle

Comment: Question to vague in my opinion. You should provide a code example of screenshot of your current problem, so we get the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`text-align: center;`

This will center the text in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

with a `margin-left: 20%;` you will be off center. (So remove this) Then, center the list items in the ul with what Matthew T. Baker suggested in the comments: `ul.navbar li {text-align:center;}`

Comment: So I just did what you suggested, but it didn't center the text, it only moved the nav bar to the far left with the text still to the right :/!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this html code.
I think your text is centered but navbar is to the right. Below code will place your navbar to center. If I understood correctly. I have tested on google chorme. It works fine. Hope it help you.

```
    <html>
     <head>
     <style>
    .navbar {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;

}

ul.navbar li 
        {
            list-style-type: none;
            float:left;
        }

a:link,a:visited  
            {
                display:block;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#C0C0C0;
                padding: 1.5em;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-transform:uppercase;
            }

a:hover,a:active  
            {
                background-color: #000066;
            }
     </style>

<body>
              <ul class="navbar">
               <li><a href=“index.html”>Home</a></li>
               <li><a href=“company.html”>Company</a></li>
               <li><a href=“services.html”>Services</a></li>
               <li><a href=“solutions.html”>Solutions</a></li>
               <li><a href=“projects.html”>Projects</a></li>
               <li><a href=“affiliations.html”>Affiliations</a></li>    
               <li><a href=“contact.html”>Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          </body>
          </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need here is that one  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jfqki)

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul.navbar 
        {  
          margin-left:0;
          margin-right:0;
            float: left;
            border: 2px solid #000066;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

ul.navbar li 
        {
            list-style-type: none;
            float:left;
        }

a:link,a:visited  
            {
                display:block;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#C0C0C0;
                padding: 1.5em;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-transform:uppercase;
            }

a:hover,a:active  
            {
                background-color: #000066;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add:

```
ul.navbar {
    padding: 0;
}

ul.navbar li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly!

Ahh I am so happy right now, thanks again!